# Modal Creation, JS Returning Null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm messing around with building a modul for a website and am making one in a new script. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and am hoping someone smarter than me can help. 
Here's the code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
     <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script>
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    document.getElementById("modl").onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "Block";
   }
   document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0].onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "none";
   };

    window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target === modal) {
          modal.style.display = 'none';
       }
    }
    </script>
</head>
     <div class="body">
        <button id="modl">open Modal</button>
     </div>
     <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <span class="close">&times;</span>
           <p>my modal text. yay!</p>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <p>some cool text that i</p>
             <p>cant think of right now</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <h3>hola</h3>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

What's happening is that it's saying either modal is null or the first function is null.

Comment: would be cool if you could add the markup so we can reproduce the problem.... are you making sure the dom is loaded first?

Comment: I added the rest. Sorry I couldn't figure out how to put html in the editor. :p

Comment: Your script is running before the HTML is loaded so your getById calls and such can't find anything. Either move the script to be after the HTML or put the js inside an onload event.

Comment: thanks I didn't realize that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the div where you are creating your modal has the next structure:

```
<div id="myModal"></div>
```

That would be my first approach, if you can upload all your code it will be more useful. Good luck!

Comment: Hey I uploaded the rest of it. Have any ideas?